# how to click on this button with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, click, browser

i trying to click this button :

```
<button type='submit' style='padding:2px 11px 4px 11px;margin-top:9px' class='tnt'>ارسال لینک</button>
</center>
<input type='hidden' name='task' value='send'/>
```

with this solutions but not working :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("submit").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.All("task").SetAttribute("value", "send")
```

and SendKeys.Send("{Enter}") is not good way.Other way?!

Comment: I think that we have to play 20 questions in order to find out what you are trying to do. Please add more details.

Comment: tnx all.                                                                         For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("submit") Then
                Element.InvokeMember("click")

                Return
            End If

        Next

Comment: Please create a reduced test case for your issue, if you want us to have a look at it. It means having a very simple page with just one button on it, and then add code that just clicks this button, and nothing else. Post all your VB code and HTML markup in the question. Thanks.